# Making a page w/ divs, images, video responsive

Tags: html, css

First off, there's a bit of CSS in this so I apologize for having to read through that. I'm still trying to learn this stuff.

For the most part, the page is responsive in the sense that I can scale it down and it adapts. However, it seems like once it hits that type of iphone resolution or it gets too small, some of the text starts disappearing, the image in the header disappears and the video that should be in the right div moves down to the footer. I'm not sure how to prevent that. Link to jsfiddle below

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="headerBlock">
    <div class="headerText"><h2 style="color:white">Header or something</h2>Blah blah text text blah blah</div>
    <div class="headerImg"><img src="/someimage.jpg" height="250" width="300">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="leftBlock">
            <img src="/sample.png" height="300" width="300">
    </div>

<div id="rightBlock">
            <div class="rightText">More text, more text, blah blah blah - video below this
             </div>
           <div class="rightVideo">
           <video autoplay loop muted>
           <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
           </video> 
           </div>
    </div>
<div id="footerBlock">
          <p>Footer Text!</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap { 
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1200px;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
}

#headerBlock { 
height: 300px; 
background:  #776b68; 
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

div.headerText {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 150px;
padding-left: 20px;
}

div.headerImg {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 100px;
}

#leftBlock { 
width: 50%; 
height: 500px; 
background-color: black;
float: left; 
position: relative;
}

#leftBlock img {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transition: transform 7s;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#leftBlock img:hover {
transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1.8);
}

#rightBlock { 
width: 50%;
height: 500px; 
background: #8ab78f; 
float: left; 
position: relative;
}

div.rightText {
padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
}

div.rightVideo {
padding: 35px 10px 0 40px; 
}

video {
width: 100%;
max-width: 500px;
height: auto;
}


#footerBlock { 
height: 200px; 
background:  #29342a ; 
clear: left; 
}

#footerBlock p {
font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", "serif";
font-size: 26px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 6%;
color: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lk7odtu/1/

Comment: The usual solution is to use @media rules to set different CSS at small screen sizes. https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create CSS sections with @media

You need to adjust the values in your #leftblock (and others) for them to fit what you need/want

ex:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 699px) {

   #leftBlock {      
   max-height: 350px;     
   }

}
```

You can actually play around with the diffenrent screen sizes, depending on your needs.

Using % instead of px is also a plan to make it more flexible.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I looked into this. Question - do I need to make a @media query for every single device? Everything from iphone4->7 plus ipads plus landscape/portrait modes?

Comment: It is possible to aime directly at specific phones since they don't all react in the same way to the CSS but if you use **screen size** and **%**, that should cover most,  Chrome has a few in-built phones/pads you can test your site on.  Although the simulation is not always 100% accurate, it is still a nice tool.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Looks like @media is the way to go here. Just gotta look a little more into it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries could definitely help infact that would be it. For mobile first you can do something like this

```
#leftBlock { 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 500px; 
        background-color: black;
        float: none; 
        position: relative;
    }
    #rightBlock { 
       width: 100%;
       height: 500px; 
       background: #8ab78f; 
      float: none; 
      position: relative;
   }

     @media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
       #leftBlock { 
        width: 50%; 
        float: left; 
    }
    #rightBlock { 
       width: 50%; 
      float: left; 
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS3 media queries for add rules for different screen sizes or use some grid, like bootstrap or flexboxgrid.